# Need help getting pixel location for Android Renderscript

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript

I am working with Android Renderscript to analyze preview frames received from Camera2API. I intend to analyze each pixel and based on some rules(dependent on intensity and location of the pixel) I need to update a counter. I intend to use a ForEach loop but how do I get the pixel coordinates.

An example java loop would be.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 240; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 320; j++)
            {
                tempPixelIntensity =  image.getPixel(i,j);
                x = i;
                y = j ;
                if(tempPixelIntensity=zzz&x<zzzandy<zzz)
                {
                     counter++;
                }
            }
        }
```

How would I go about doing the same in a renderscript? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed   // needed for some GPUs
uint32_t counter;
void RS_KERNEL process(uchar tempPixelIntensity, uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    if(tempPixelIntensity=zzz&x<zzzandy<zzz)
    {
        rsAtomicInc(&counter);
    }
}
```

RS kernels are SPMD (single program multiple data). So you write only the inner part of your loop for a single pixel element and the framework does the looping.

In the java side you will do something like:

```
 Type.Builder tb = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs));
 tb.setX(320);
 tb.setY(240);
 Allocation input = Allocation.createTyped(rs, tb.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
 script.forEach_process(input);
```

So the dimensions of the input allocation determines the bounds that the kernel will operate over. In this case x will vary from [0,319] and y will vary from [0,239]. The x,y parameters to the kernel are special parameters that are filled in by the RS runtime, similarly the tempPixelIntensity value will be populated by the value of the input allocation pixel at the given x,y coordinate.

Comment: How does the x and y get populated? Do we need to set max x and max y at launch options?

Comment: x/y are populated by the dimensions of the input allocation, you don't need to set launch options unless the dimensions of the input allocation are not conducive to the execution of your algorithm. For example if you wanted each kernel thread to process 2 or more pixels at a time instead of one.

Comment: Oh. That does make sense. Can I just pass the output from another method in the script to the next one using allocations? Do I need to reformat it before I do so? The other method gives me a bitmap image as an output

Comment: Yes, one allocation can be the output of one kernel and the input of another. You just need to ensure the types match, for instance if you have a U8 allocation, use uchar in RS. If you have RGBA_8888 use uchar4. As far as the bitmap image, there is a method Allocation.createFromBitmap that will initialize an Allocation with your bitmap data.